# How to disable all stylesheets in Prestashop?

Tags: css, stylesheet, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How can I prevent all Prestashop's stylesheets from being included? By all I mean *any* stylesheet that is automatically added by CMS to website's `<head>` section.

I need this to use a single external stylesheet instead (my own, not the one generated by CCC).

It would be perfect to use non-JS method, but I'm not sure if it is possible in admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just open header.tpl file from your theme folder and remove the following code:

```
{if isset($css_files)}
{foreach from=$css_files key=css_uri item=media}
<link href="{$css_uri}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="{$media}" />
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: ok  , and can you please tell me how to remove a specific css url from prestashop